# Google Merchant Center Ignoring Price values in product feed

Tags: google-ads, feeds, shopping

Running Google Shopping advertising for a client who sells nutritional supplements. They have two different pricing options, one-off purchases or ongoing subscriptions. The subscription price is around 10% cheaper per product, but you have to commit to buying the same product for three months.

We want to advertise the one-off purchase price in our Google Shopping ads, because if you only want one of the product this would be the cheapest option.

Unfortunately, Google Merchant Center has decided to take the subscription price from the landing page and use it in place of the one-off purchase price included in the product feed. This is despite the structured data on the page deliberately excluding the subscription pricing options. The product report in the Merchant Center clearly states what they have done, that they have taken the cheaper prices from the landing page, despite these being inappropriate.

I have looked and Google does have a subscription-cost value that can be used in the product feed. But this value is only for mobile phones and the like, and not appropriate for our client.

We'd prefer to not have duplicate pages for each product to have the subscription pricing kept off the landing pages.

Is there anything we can do to prevent Google from taking these cheaper, but incorrect prices from our landing pages?